# Lack of file explorer in Linux vim

Tags: linux, vim

In vim 7.3 on OSX, if I type

```
vim ~/myfiles
```

vim will put me into the Vim File Explorer for that directory, and I can open or rename files.

In vim 7.4 on Ubuntu, I get the unhelpful error message

```
"~/myfiles" is a directory
```

Looking through the compiled options (vim --version) and online documentation, I see no obvious way to activate this functionality through, say, a command-line or compile-time option.  It is such a great feature of vim that I'm surprised it is not enabled on the version of vim available in the Linux package.

Comment: Consider installing the [Nerdtree plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) for vim. It's a must-have.

Comment: Do you have any plugins in vim OSX version? If you try in OSX `vim --noplugin ~/myfiles` I bet it'll not work.

Comment: Are you sure you have the full vim installed rather than vim-tiny? Check by running `ls -l /etc/alternatives/vim`

Comment: Indeed, on OSX `vim --noplugin ~/myfiles` does not work.

Comment: `ls -l /etc/alternatives/vim` shows a link to `/usr/bin/vim.gnome`.  The `/usr/bin` directory also has `vim.basic` and `vim.tiny`.

Comment: I use [ranger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_%28file_manager%29) file manager and a little [.vimrc function](http://ornicar.github.io/2011/02/12/ranger-as-vim-file-manager.html) to open it from within Vim. It works wonderfully.

Comment: I got `vim ~/myfiles` to show a directory by installing the Nerdtree plugin (thank you, radubogdan!), and this worked both on Ubuntu and on OSX (with the new directory explorer).  Somehow, though, the repository for my `.vim` on Github got all messed up (re: submodules).  I ended up creating a fresh repository and reconstructing my submodules, and got everything to work again _except_ for Nerdtree on Ubuntu.  Will try again tomorrow; it is late here...

Comment: Installing Nerdtree plugin did solve the problem, though not before I learned more about git submodules than I had bargained for -- but would be another thread.  The suggestion to use Nerdtree was not posted as an 'answer', so how would I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize and answer my own question...

File explorer functionality is actually provided by a plug-in, "netrw", which seems not to be installed by default in the two or three versions of vim I tried via apt-get.

Installing [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) solved the problem brilliantly - it can do so much more than the default explorer.  I have not yet figured out how to rename a file using NERDTree - something that is easy with 'netrw', but that is a minor irritant and there is probably a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:E` command for the explorer mode.

Comment: I don't think the OP intended to switch to the mode while in vim but to start it in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to edit a directory like this depends on a plugin. Most of the time, that plugin is the "netrw" plugin provided with Vim in the official runtime files. In Ubuntu (and Debian) you install that runtime separately so that every Vim package can use it rather than duplicating functionality. Try installing the vim-runtime package, and maybe a more feature-full Vim while you are at it, if you have not already done so.